# Regular expression to get characters between first and second occurance of specific string

Tags: mysql, regex

How to write a regular expression that matches characters between first '/' and second '/'.

Example :
5/2/266/267 (Expected Output : 2)

68/567/8/56 (Expected Output : 567)

......

Similarly also how write the regex that matches characters between second '/' and third '/'.
Example :
5/2/266/267 (Expected Output : 266)

68/567/8/56 (Expected Output : 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use this one:

```
 ^[^\/]*\/([^\/]+?)\/.*
```

Comment: Thanks That's working. Similarly how do i match characters between second '/' and third '/'.

Comment: ^([^\/]*/){2}([^\/]+?)\/.* but you need to take or replace to \2 same for third change {2} to {3} and so on

Comment: There is some problem in your regular expression. I am testing it over here http://rubular.com  (String : 5/2/266/267) (Expected Output : 266)

Comment: if you have digits you can use this one ^(?:\d*?\/){2}(\d+?)\/

Answer (score 1):

Largely depends on the engine, but most should support the reluctant quantifier.  This will work at least in JavaScript, PHP, ruby, python, and possibly others:

```
/(.*?)/
```

You may need to escape delimiters, e.g. `\/`

Comment: Thanks That's working. Similarly how do i match characters between second '/' and third '/'.

Comment: @RajeshAshokKumar it seems like you probably want to use a utility like `split` that many languages have.

Comment: Here I am using regex function in mysql query.

Comment: @RajeshAshokKumar that I know of MySQL does not allow you to do regular expression replacement in any way.  Seems like you should select the values first and then parse them.  A possible expression to see the second would be: `/.*/(.*?)/`

Comment: Here is the regex for mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 0):

A pattern like this would work:

```
/([^/]*)/
```

Or possibly using lookarounds:

```
(?<=/)[^/]*(?=/)
```

Note however, that many regular expression engines use `/` to delimit regular expression literals. In that case, you'd need to escape the `/` like this:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=\/)
```

Comment: @RajeshAshokKumar Specify what platform / engine you're using and please explain what's not working about it.

Comment: @Darka It will probably depend on the how you use it and the semantics of your platform.

Comment: I am regexp function in mysql. I am testing the regular expression over here. http://rubular.com/

Comment: @RajeshAshokKumar Can you show your SQL query and explain precisely what you're trying to do? It's likely there is a better solution not involving regular expressions.